# Local and Remote data store sync

Tags: mysql, xml, windows, ms-access, database-replication

I have a situation where I would like a desktop application to be useable whether an internet connection is present or not.

I have a choice of MySQL on a web server and I could work with a local MySQL database or maybe MS Access database on the local drive and then just update data when connection is restored. My issues are as follows.

1. Sync local changes to remote server. Multi site  / multi user scenario so how to keep db in sync when connection restored without loosing changes from other users in server data.
2. Sync remote changes to local. Multi site  / multi user scenario so how to keep db in sync when connection restored without loosing changes made locally while updating with server data.

Currently I am using XML files and LingtoXML querying but it is unsatisfactory to continue with these files so a better solution is required.

Any help would be appreciated to identify what technology would work best and how to keep them in sync.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

"Jet Replication Objects (JRO)", the replication features of the Access Database Engine, have been deprecated (ref: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810810.aspx#bkmk_DepMDAC_WDACComps)). I believe that the related management features have also been completely removed from Access 2013. Therefore, native Access replication should no longer be considered a viable option.

Microsoft's recommendation would be to use SQL Server and its replication features. However, SQL Server Express has limitations on how much it can do (e.g., it can be a "Subscriber" but not a "Publisher" or "Distributor", ref: [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165686%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)) so presumably there would have to be a non-free copy of SQL Server involved somehow.

I haven't yet had the occasion to use MySQL replication myself, but it is probably worth considering. Chances are good that you could still use Access as a front-end (via ODBC linked tables).